# jquery validation rule for contains

Tags: jquery, validation

is there way to create a rule in the jquery validiation plugin that allows you to say not contains "value"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can [add method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notcontainfoo", function(value, element) { 
  return value != 'foo'; 
}, "You can't fill this with 'foo' !! ");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
doesnotContain: function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || !(value.indexOf(param)>=0);
},
```

Something like that?